# npm install error when following Angular2 5 min quickstart

Tags: node.js, npm, angular

I get an error when following the Angular2 5 min quick start. How can I get past it?

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/angular2-tutorial$ sudo npm install   angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 /vagrant/angular2-tutorial
└── foxy@11.1.4  extraneous

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.6
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-74-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path /vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/.staging/lodash-496d43d7
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/.staging/lodash-496d43d7' -> '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/lodash'
npm ERR!     at destStatted (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install/action/finalize.js:25:7)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/.staging/lodash-496d43d7' -> '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/lodash'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/.staging/lodash-496d43d7' -> '/vagrant/angular2-tutorial/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/lodash'] parent: 'browser-sync' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-74-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.727051537
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename 'npm-debug.log.727051537' -> 'npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/angular2-tutorial/npm-debug.log
```

Here is the error log:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xr6ha3z4re0npvi/npm-debug.log.727051537?dl=0

Comment: Perhaps a permission problem?

Comment: What more can I try than add sudo before the command?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the permission issue. The `npm` is configured to put downloaded modules to a directory that is not authorized.

You can configure `npm` to install the modules to a custom directory with its `prefix` configuration.

Refer to following articles:

[Use one of these techniques to install node and npm without having to sudo](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814)

[Installing Node and npm](https://www.joyent.com/blog/installing-node-and-npm/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I reinstalled node using the top technique in the list you referenced. I still get errors when trying npm install